# IE8 and IE9 will not properly render 960 grid

Tags: css, internet-explorer, 960.gs

Rookie here learning about 960 grid and css as I go along.  I've managed to resolve most of my issues by a thorough search here, but am really struggling with my page rendering improperly on all IE8 and IE9 (though it somehow renders fine in IE7/8 compatibility view).

In IE, my main content (6-col, 6-col, 4-col) is truncating the last column to the bottom of the page in spite of screen resolution or zoom.  It renders fine in all other browsers (minus a known issue with the "outline" definition in FF).  I'm aware that IE has a problem with margins and/or padding, though I don't fully understand the issue yet.  However, I have no horizontal padding that I can find that might result in more than 960 pixels.  If someone more knowledgeable would take a quick look at my css, I hope that they can point me in the right direction.

As I mentioned, I'm learning css and this grid system as I go along.  I'm no web programmer, just a guy with Google and Web Expressions on his computer trying to build a site for a non-profit agency.  I'm sure there are some serious semantic issues with the code, but I thank you for being gentle.  I promise to clean up my code as I better understand proper semantics.  Thanks.

Comment: IE has problems with a lot more than just margin and padding. It looks like 960 uses media queries which don't work in IE8 for one.

Comment: I dreamed up the idea to remove all css and add it back in, one section at a time, in order to isolate the problem.  Turns out that it's a div class (.submenustyle) where display:none property is applied.  This property hides a UL submenu in the navigation band and some JS magic displays the appropriate submenu based on hover over the main menu.  The JS is doing the job it's supposed to, but when the submenustyle div is not displayed, it is throwing IE out of whack.  Can anyone help me understand why this happens and/or recommend a change/hack/whatever to make it render properly in IE? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was wrong about the trouble-maker code.  It was actually some unnecessary (and at the time, seemingly harmless) code in the css for the left portion of the div that houses my company logo...specifically, display:inherit and width=100%.  After deleting these two lines, everything renders nicely in IE7+.